# Alternate way for setimeout in angular

Tags: angular, settimeout

I am using Angular 13 I need to know what is the alternate way for using `setTimeout`

```
  wantout(){
    if(this.wantin.valid){
      this.postfunction(this.data)
      var _one = this.router;
      setTimeout(function(){
        _one.navigate(['/','/goon'])
      },100);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RXJS Interval:
https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval

```
import { interval, take } from 'rxjs';

const numbers = interval(1000);

const takeFourNumbers = numbers.pipe(take(4));

takeFourNumbers.subscribe(x => console.log('Next: ', x));

// Logs:
// Next: 0
// Next: 1
// Next: 2
// Next: 3
```

Comment: sorry i don't quiet understand how should i use this in my above question?